# remove white spaces and add corresponding value

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract text data from a yearly sales book stored in a text file

Link for the file [click here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kL_9AoWhex8GjGTboeI9flrJFFSaDxCJ)

I decided to tackle this problem by removing the white spaces between content and their numbers by replacing it with ','(comma) making it a csv type text. However, I'm facing the issue for year row since it doesn't have any corresponding value.

*For sales of 200 in the year 1990 corresponding value is ABC, for 9 sales in 1991 corresponding value is DEF but for year we do not have the corresponding value causing the year to shift to the left.*

**My problem is how to make sure that year doesn't shift to left and the year and values fall correctly under a single column when converting this to a CSV file**

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow :)  What have you tried to do so far? Showing some code you've tried to write would be helpful for us to understand what's going wrong so that we can help you.

Comment: The first row is kind of special, not an ordinary row, it's header. So make special function `readHeader` and rather than reading everything with same function, first read a header and then your data.

Comment: @hradecek Thanks for the suggestion. I have created the readHeader method and passed "Notes" as string to be appended before reading any header. Thanks for the suggestion once again :)